# jQuery: slideToggle and instant callback without micro pause

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have little problem with jQuery slideToggle callback.

I have something like this:

```
$("#nav").slideToggle('normal',function(){
  $(this).find(".nav").slideToggle();
});
```

And after sliding `#nav` is micropause and then sliding `.nav`, i need to remove this micropause.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2jYc7/1/

Comment: then take the inner slideToggle out of the finished callback and call it along side the other: http://jsfiddle.net/2jYc7/4/

Comment: @PatrickEvans your fiddle is bugging, atleast in chrome..

Comment: i dont wanna call both slides at the same time, i need to call that inner slide after first slide finished, but instantly. Without any delays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a 'delay'. The default jQuery ease (which I *think* is `swing`) makes it look like a delay. Change both easing effects to 'linear', and you'll get what your looking for:

```
$("#nav-toggler").on("click", function () {
    $("#nav").slideToggle({
        done: function () {
            $(this).find(".nav").slideToggle({
                easing: 'linear'
            });
        },
        easing: 'linear'
    });
})
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/2jYc7/12/)

Also, `live()` is deprecated since 1.7, use `on()` instead.

Comment: Look at my answer, it's so much less code than this and solves your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21531307/1477388

Comment: @user1477388 It doesn't do the same thing. Here, the second animation is called after the first has finished. In your example, `.nav` is already visible when `#nav` is toggled.

Comment: @user1477388, nope, i need do slide div one after another- your code dont do that.

Comment: Ahh I see.  I didn't think you wanted that since it looks weird :)  Btw, I didn't downvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the selector on the container element. Also don't use `live` . It has been replaced by `on`

```
$("#nav-toggler").on("click",function(){
    $(".cont").slideToggle('normal');
})

.cont{display:none;padding:30px;}
#nav{padding:20px 0;background:red;}
#nav .nav{padding:20px 0;background:green;}
```